# Adding a Javascript library

Tags: 8, bootstrap-theme

I apologize for asking this for the 100th time but I just cannot understand the previous answers.   There are 2 modules ([form placeholder](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_placeholder) and [chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen))where cannot get their libraries included.

Step 1: I downloaded their libraries and placed them in the `libraries` folder.
Step 2: I included 2 new libraries in the `THEME.info.yml`

```
libraries-extend:
  bootstrap/framework:
    - bootstrap_kampuster/framework

libraries:
  - bootstrap_kampuster/chosen
  - jquery.placeholder
```

However, neither one of the 2 is loading right now. Is there anything else I need to add somewhere? FYI, my `THEME.libraries.yml` looks like this;

```
framework:
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
      css/animate.min.css: {}
 
  js:
    js/custom.js: {}
    js/misc/waypoints.min.js: {}
      
    dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Comment: What is bootstrap loading, from local or a CDN?

Comment: @joehoe, hi there, loading bootstrap from local.

Comment: [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to YOURTHEME.theme file:

```
function siderise_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  // Attach the global-scripts library to all blocks.
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'YOURTHEME/YOURFRAMEWORK';
}
```

make sure you update the function with your theme and your framework in the bottom line